# "Missing needed parameter state" when hitting the /auth/complete/ url?

Tags: python, django

I'm using the Python social auth with a custom backend. Here is my code so far:

```
from requests import HTTPError
from social.backends.oauth import BaseOAuth2
from social.exceptions import AuthFailed

class MyOAuth2(BaseOAuth2):
    #testing OAuth authentication backend
    name = 'testing'
    AUTHORIZATION_URL = 'https://<my_drupal_oauth2_server>/oauth2/authorize'
    ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = 'https://<my_drupal_oauth2_server>/oauth2/token'
    SCOPE_SEPARATOR = ','
    STATE_PARAMETER = 'False'
    REDIRECT_STATE = 'False'
    EXTRA_DATA = [
        ('id', 'id'),
        ('expires', 'expires'),
    ]

def get_user_details(self, response):
    #Return user details from test account
    return {'username': response.get('login'),
            'email': response.get('email') or '',
            'first_name': response.get('name')}

#def user_data(self, access_token, *args, **kwargs):
#    #Loads user data from service
```

This is my first attempt to implement an OAuth2 setup using a custom back end -- first attempt to write one.

The OAuth2 server works with Google's OAuth2 playground. My django app (which is Open edX) however is throwing the error.

If I manually add `?state=xyz` to the url, I get another error:

> Session value state missing

I've searched for good information on both of these errors and I'm coming up short on what a root cause might be, and a solution.

Comment: Could you add the entire error to your question?

Comment: Ridiculous as this is, the only error there is, is "Missing needed parameter state" and it is the entirety of the error. I have yet to find a way to get a full stack trace.